# JPA How to determine use @OneToOne or @OneToMany

Tags: java, jpa

guys!
I have a  `@OneToOne` or `@OneToMany` question.
There a table of `production` And there is a table of `price_list`.
A production that in `production` table have a price which in `price_list` table.
But `price_list` have history price and current price of one production which meant a production can map many `price_list` record. The current price is mark by field `status` which equal 1.
My question is how to find the current price quickly by using `@OneToOne` or `@OneToMany`
Thanks!

Comment: suppose you need `@OneToMany` because there are history prices also. think you need to use query `findPirceByStatus(Long productId)` to get the current prize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do

1. You may create a View (e.g. `current_price`) in your database, which contains only `price_list` records with `status = 1`.  In your entity, you can map it as separate entity.
2. Similar to above, if your `price_list` has a nice ID, you may make the view as a relationship, so you can map to same `Price` entity as a separate relationship
3. If you don't mind using Hibernate-specific feature, you may use `@Where`
4. If it is just needed for some specific query instead of general behavior of entity, you may simply have a query like

   ```
   select new ProductCurrentPrice(product, price) 
   from Product product
   left join product.priceList price
   where product = ... and price.status = ACTIVE
   ```
5. If number of prices for a product is not huge, you may simply get the whole list and do the filtering in entity:

   ```
   class Product {
       @OneToMany
       List<Price> prices;

       Optional<Price> getCurrentPrice() {
           prices.stream().filter(p->p.status==ACTIVE).findFirst();
       }
   }
   ```

I believe are other ways to do.

Comment: Thanks very much.It's helpful. If I create View map to entity,can I update the entity?

Comment: depending on which way (1 or 2) you are taking.  For 1, it also depends on the DBMS you are using.  Oracle should be fine.  Not sure about other DBMS

Comment: Thanks again. I will take your suggesion (3..5). Are u in HK? Can you speak  Chinese?

Comment: Good guess.  I am in HK and I know Chinese.  However I'd rather not to use it here as SO is a Q&A site for the whole world

Answer (score -1):

Use @OneToMany and pass the status as to get the current price in query in view or stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks.How to pass the status to a entity? Can u give me a sample.

Comment: This will give you an incomplete entity and I believe there is no way that Hibernate will know it is incomplete, hence subsequent retrieval of the entity from the first level cache will always give you that incomplete entity

Comment: @AdrianShum You are right in hibernate it will give the list of all prices. I mentioned the query (even in your answer you mention the same thing.)

Comment: @SumitGulati I think you need to be clear on your suggestion.  Yours can be interpreted as `from product join fetch product.prices p where product = ... and p.status = ACTIVE` which is going to cause problem

Comment: @AdrianShum Sure I second you it will give wrong result. I will clarify more but you already gave the answer so it will not make sense to repeat the same stuff. I will take care in future. Thanks.